# PptxGenJS - Issue with NPM declaration of file

Tags: npm, types, package, declaration, pptxgenjs

I'm trying to work with **PPTXGenJS** in a **SharePoint's** *WebPart* and therefore need to import the npm package.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to make it available in my program, since code is telling me that a declaration file is missing.
`npm install @types/pptxgenjs@latest` just throws an error and even appending a new **pptxgenjs.d.ts** file declaring the module does not work.

Do you have any ideas what I can do here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Types were made available by the author the old way (DefinitelyTyped). This is the reason why "npm install @types/pptxgenjs@latest" does not work.

Try "npm install pptxgenjs", or add it to your dependencies in the package.json file, like this:

"dependencies": {
"pptxgenjs": "^2.3.0"
}

This will install the dependency, and types will be available at dist/pptxgenjs

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this before, but unfortunately the code that is loaded with the npm install pptxgenjs is not the latest. I manually had to post the code from the git-repo into my index.d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

environment: node 16.18.0 + typescript: 4.3.5

running command: `ts-code test.ts`

After research for hours, this solution works for me:

```
// test.ts
const PptxFile = require('pptxgenjs');
const pptx = new PptxFile();
let slide = pptx.addSlide();
slide.addText('Hello World from PptxGenJS...');
pptx.writeFile({ fileName: 'Sample Presentation.pptx' });
```